# What the [Flipkart]...?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I was reading a new question when I saw a weird [flipkart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flipkart) tag:

> Flipkart is an online Shopping of Books, Mobile Phones, Digital Cameras, Laptops, Watches, Clothing & Other Products at Best Price in India

This isn't only a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), it is also off-topic (I don't see how the Stack Overflow's community could be benefited by knowing that Flipkart is an online Indian shop).

I see that there are questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719603/flipkart-affiliate-client-node-404-not-found-on-product-search) which refers to the `flipkart-affiliate-client` NPM package, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608043/flipkart-api-post-v3-shipments-filter-throwing-error) that refers to the Flipkart API, but that, if anything, should be their own tag.

Can we burninate [flipkart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flipkart)?

Comment: While we're at it shouldn't tags like `Google` or any other "brand" be burninated?

Comment: what if you simply rewrite the tag wiki and excerpt so it refers to/is to be used for the API of flipkart. The questions you picked are on-topic. The only thing that is bothering is the roaring sales pitch talk of the tag.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @AaronN.Brock. Then why not remove `Amazon` tag as well which says *Amazon is a US-based multinational e-commerce company.* or any other similar to that matter

Comment: @Rahul To be honest, I don't see a reason for an [tag:amazon] to exist. But the Google tag was blacklisted, so there you go

Comment: @AaronN.Brock As I commented above, the Google tag was blacklisted for this same reason...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I wasn't asking that ironically, I think there might be merit to burninating those tags, I was just trying to broaden the discussion.

Comment: I think rene is right. Most of the questions seem on-topic, since they involve API calls. A rename to [flipkart-api] with a tag cleanup seems more appropriate than a burninate. I made the tag excerpt clear that the existing tag is only for API calls

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just rewrite the excerpt to remove the sales pitch (that text seems plagiarized anyway):

> Use this tag for questions about the Affiliate API of the Flipkart online shop.

Most of the questions asked seem on-topic and about that API. I see a couple of broad ones so at best a clean-up is in order.

If anything, rename it to [flipkart-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flipkart-api) if the tag name itself causes that much of an itch.

Comment: Shouldn't the tag be [tag:flipkart-api] to avoid tagging like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491620/helper-screens-at-android-app-startup

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure, flipkart-api could be a sensible rename.

Comment: I've done it in the way this answer mentioned. Closed all the off-topic posts, deleted the unsalvagable ones, removed the tag where it was not needed and renamed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

`Flipkart` as a tag doesn't go here as stackoverflow(SO) is related to programming stuff while Flipkart is a commercial site.

Renaming `Flipkart` to `Flipkart-API` is sensible for SO.

Just explaining for those who are from India (even I'm from India) and taking this in a different manner, the `Flipkart` tag goes well for a forum related to shopping or similar. This addition of API rule goes well not particularly for flipkart or amazon or alibaba etc but for any such brandings, those are not directly related to programming.

A question with such brand tags makes it feel that the question is related to shopping or an inquiry about the quality of a product of that brand.